# Badge points 6/5?

Tags: discussion, badges

There is this strange indication in my profile:

[image]

What does it mean?

Is it possible bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means that the system has noticed that you meet one of the requirements for this tag, but you haven't been awarded the tag yet.

If  you click on it it says:

[image]

Note the *need positive question record*.

You have three deleted questions with 0 or less score.

You just need to continue asking *good* questions and you will be awarded this badge eventually.

Additionally, the system only gives out some tags at specific times (like once per 3 hours or once per day). But in this case it is the positive question record that is preventing you from getting this badge.